# Bootstrap 3 data-toggle collapse doesn't animate on second item on page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to implement the Bootstrap 3 `data-toggle="collapse"` on a menu. I have a search bar that uses data-toggle and it works well, but on the menu, although the menu appears and disappears, it doesn't animate. I can't figure out why. I believe I have followed the Bootstrap documentation.

Here is a stripped down version of my code that displays the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/7g7y4ykh/1/

Search bar toggle code:

```
<a class="btn-search collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".search-collapse">
    <span class="search-toggle"></span>
</a>
```

Search bar code:

```
<div id="topsearch" class="collapse search-collapse">
    ...
</div>
```

Menu toggle code:

```
<a class="btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topmenu">
    <span class="pancakes"></span>
</a>
```

Menu bar code:

```
<div id="topmenu" class="topmenu-nav collapse">
    ...
</div>
```

If you click on the search link, a little search bar slides into view. If you click the menu link, the menu just appears - no sliding. How can I make it slide?